# How to find the second value with same CSS class using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, css, selenium, webdriver

I want to select from a li (it looks like a dropdown but it is not) the second value (in my example, `Bellevue`). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am using Page Objects and I am looking after elements using @FindBy annonations. Here is what I tried:

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS,using = "a[id^='ui-id-'][1]")
```

I receive the error:

```
The given selector a[id*='ui-id-'](1) is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement
```

or using

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS,using = "a[id^='ui-id-']"[1])`
```

I get the error:

```
the type of expression must be an array but it resolved to string`.
```

It worked if I used:

```
WebElement value = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id^='ui-id']")).get(3);
```

value.click();

but I must use `@FindBy` and I can not get it to work on get(3) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't index elements using `[]` in CSS selectors.

Here is what you might want to try:

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS,using = "li.ui-menu-item:nth-of-type(2) > a[id^='ui-id-']")
```

Or use XPath

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using = "(//a[starts-with(@id, 'ui-id-')])[2]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create some method where you access needed element without web element defined with `FindBy` annotation. For example

```
public void yourMethod(WebDriver driver) {
   WebElement value = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id^='ui-id']")).get(3); 
   value.click();
}
```

Comment: what is Driver.getInstance()? because i get the error:`Driver cannot be resolved`.it is not from something i didn't import.

Comment: yes,i thought of that before...i think i will use this method if I can't manage to use @FindBy

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can use XPath to do something like this:
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using = "(//a[contains(@class, 'ui-id-')])[2]")
where the final [2] specifies the second element returned by the previous XPath.

(sorry, I'm working from memory - I haven't tested this specific XPath)